# uninstall SQL server 2008 r2 from SharePoint 2013 server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server, uninstallation

We have installed SharePoint 2013 on a server and one of the SQL engineers has also installed SQL server 2008 r2 on the same server where SharePoint is installed. ?Though that SQL server is not connected to SP farm, We have a separate SQL instance to which it is connected.

So, this SQL server 2008 r2 is redundant, do we need to follow any particular procedure to uninstall SQL server from SharePoint server?

Does uninstalling causes any issues to SharePoint FARM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SQL server 2008 r2 is not connected to the SharePoint 2013 farm , it will not affect the sharepoint 2013 farm when you uninstall the SQL server 2008 r2 from the SharePoint server.

You could uninstall the SQL server 2008 r2 from the SharePoint server as usual.

Then you could follow the steps in the articles below to uninstall SQL server 2008 r2.

[How to uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2008.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/955499/how-to-uninstall-an-instance-of-sql-server-2008)

[How to Uninstall a SQL Server Instance in SQL Server 2008R2 and 2008.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c1f7d5/how-to-uninstall-a-sql-server-instance-in-sql-server-2008r2/)